# Require in VueJS

Tags: vuejs2

so I'm having a bit of a problem with this. I have a navigation on my page. The problem is when I create a new page I have to rewrite my whole navigation. If something changes, I have to make that change in all of my pages.

I want to see if there is a way to "require" my navigation in all of my templates. In PHP I could use `require "navigation.html";` and it would load my navigation on the page, is their a similar function as this in VueJS?

Comment: Do you have a component? and you want to require this component in all your templates right?

Comment: I have a navigation written inside my `<template>` tag. I want to require what is written inside the `template` in my other templates..

Comment: in all other templates or selected ones?

Comment: Selected ones. :)

Comment: then give the component to your selected ones

Comment: That's what I'm trying to figure out, how do I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Vuejs componens can be defined as local or global depending on where you want to use your components.

For example:

This is our component:

```
Vue.component('hello', {template: `<p> Hello </p>`});
```

and this is our Vue instance:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app'
})
```

and doing this:

```
<div id="#app">
  <hello />
</div>
```

Would show hello component, anywhere inside your `div#app` because we have created a global compoent:

If you want to show your component for specific component, then pass the component name as:

```
<template>
 <div>
  <hello />
 </div>
</template>

<script>
var hello = {
  template: `<p> Hello </p>`
}
export default {
  components: {
    'hello': hello
  }
}
```

In the second example you will have a hello component only avaiable to the component you register it into

Comment: I'm getting this error: 

`Module build failed: SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ",". 

Vue.component('hello', template: `<p> Hello </p>`)`
                                                   ^

Comment: Ah ok, that removed the error. But now I'm getting this when using the <hello /> component: `[Vue warn]: You are using the runtime-only build of Vue where the template compiler is not available. Either pre-compile the templates into render functions, or use the compiler-included build.`

Comment: This means you are not use webpack or vue-cli, are you just using `vue.js` ?

Comment: I created my project with the vue-cli using `vue create my-project`. I'm running `npm run serve` to run my project.

Comment: It must be a render issue the, check this answer: https://github.com/vuejs-templates/webpack/issues/215#issuecomment-252988375

Comment: Seems that I don't have a webpack config file. Can I create one using the cli?

Comment: Well that's strange. If you installed vue via the cli you should have a folder called config where webpack settings are mentioned

Comment: These were the only files created when I started my project: https://image.ibb.co/eOwnX7/Screen_Shot_2018_03_29_at_11_08_42_AM.png. I'll try to create a new project with a starting template and see if it works then. Thanks for you help so far, I'll make sure to get back to you when I test it out. :)

Answer (score 0):

You only need to import your component to another component/main JS.

*Another component*

```
<template>
    <yourcomponent/>
</template>

<script>
import yourComponent from './yourpath';
export default {
    name: 'component',
    components: {
       'yourcomponent': yourComponent
    }
}
</script>
```

*Main JS*

```
import yourComponent from './yourpath';
new Vue({
    el: '#root',
    components: {
       'yourcomponent': yourComponent
    }
});
```